# Raspberry PI SD Card bottlenecking write to USB SSD

Tags: raspberry-pi, ssd

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspian from a 16gb SD Card (write speed 10). I've mounted a 4TB Samsung 860 QVO SSD with a USB3.0 to SATA cable.

I was expecting read/write speeds of around 150mb/s to the SSD, as that is what I get on other computers (Windows and a Ubuntu computer with the OS on an SSD). However the write speed to the mounted SSD is 11mb/s. I'm not entirely sure what is bottle necking it, my first thought is that it is being bottle necked by the 10mb/s read/write of the SD card that the OS is stored on, but I am not sure. Could this be the issue?

Comment: There is a sticky post at the raspberry forum regarding some devices with extremely low speed: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=245931.

Comment: I tried this and it made no difference. The problems outlined in that forum post aren't consistent with the problem I have been having.

Comment: If you suspect the SD card run a `dd if=/dev/zero of=testfile...` test to see what speed you get. What exactly do you do with the mounted SSD? I have a similar issue with a USB 3 pen drive when copying data from a USB 3 HDD. A `dd` test on the pen drive gives a speed around 150 MB/s while copying from HDD results almost in USB speed.

Comment: On the SD card I get 18mb/s and on the mounted SSD I get 4.1mb/s with the `dd if=/dev/zero of=testfile...` . I am hoping to use the mounted SSD as a fast file server, writing to it via either FileZilla or a custom Flask APP.

Comment: No, it's not that. The sd card and the usb3 are on completely different interfaces on the rp4. Did you get those speeds on the PC with the same USB3 to SATA cable, or by connecting the SSD directly? Also, you're talking about "mounted SSD": what filesystem are you using?

Comment: Add all the details and clarifications to your Q, together with the exact model of your cable (`lsusb -v`).